# WAMR: relocation truncated to fit' when build with pthread library

Tags: webassembly, wasi

I am trying to compile WAMR with pthread library on zephyr os.
I used the command in the root of my project:
`west build . -b qemu_cortex_a53 -p always -- -DWAMR_BUILD_LIB_PTHREAD=1 -DWAMR_BUILD_TARGET=AARCH64`

The compilation of each .c is successful but during the linking phase, this error occurs:
`wamr/core/iwasm/libraries/thread-mgr/thread_manager.c:1084:(.text.wasm_cluster_exit_thread+0xa8): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_JUMP26 against undefined symbol 'os_thread_exit' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Or

`undefined reference to 'os_thread_exit'`

This error replicates for all functions with the prefix `os_` within `thread_mgr.c`.
I have already checked that the CMakeList of `thread_mgr` is correctly included in the libs.

How can I fix this?
Thank you very much